# Commitizen in command line: Is there a way to go back to a previous field?

Tags: git, commitizen

I'm using the npm package [commitizen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commitizen) for my git commits. Great tool.

Upon running `cz`: Whenever I fill some fields, and then realise I want to make a change before submitting, I have to Ctrl+C and start all over again.

Surely there must be a better way? (for example a command that can start again with the fields pre-filled to whatever values were left in them). I've searched the commitizen npm, github, and generally on Google, but with no success.

Is there a feature that helps with this?

Comment: This is not quite what you're asking, I know, but I would complete the commit with the errors in it and use `git commit --amend` to make the changes I wanted after. Thanks for the pointer to commitizen, by the way, I think I'll try it: I keep forgetting the list of commit types I'm supposed to use, so this might help me.